# Pycharm: How to focus on Editor when hit a debug point

Tags: python, pycharm

I am using a mac, with Pycharm version 2018.2.4 Community version.

When I run a debugging session using the debugger and hit a debug point, I have to click on my editor using my mouse to be able to type code on the editor. If I don't do this and hit my keyboard directly, Mac will complain with some "bing" sound, signaling the keyboard input is not valid to any application (my opinion).

How to make my Pycharm auto focus on the editor when hitting the debug point? Or at least focus on the debugger so that I can hit ESC to focus on the editor?

I have selected "Focus application on breakpoint" in the setting.
[image]

Comment: How do you **exactly** run the debug session? Let's say you have edited your code, you saved the file, (the cursor is on the editor, where you last changed the file). What are the exact steps you take (include, mouse, keyboard events)? I don't have an *OSX* env set up, I'll try reproducing on *Win*.

Comment: Are you sure the behavior you're looking for is available in PyCharm? My PyCharm requires me to click in the editor if I want to type during debugging also.

Comment: How come didn't the answer solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is how it should work:

> In `Preferences`, type `Focus application on breakpoint` into the search bar and be sure it is toggled on.
>
> Apply that setting and exit `Preferences`.
>
> In your debugger, when you hit a breakpoint, hit the escape key, and your cursor should be blinking in your editor.

For me, I had to disable the setting, apply, re-enable the setting and re-apply once more.

It now behaves as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug reported on PyCharm for the same. Here is the [link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-31218) to the issue. The bug is reported for version 2018.2 and still not fixed.