# break points in pycharm 2020.3

Tags: debugging, pycharm

I am new to Pycharm and I have the below code with a breakpoint on 'print' (I have more code underneath this break point). When i run on debug, previously it would bring me to the debugger window to show me my variables up to the breakpoint. Now it doesn't and it stays on the console view and i have to manually click on the debugger view. Can someone please help me?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
print() # breakpoint is here
```

I have attached a screenshot below with the console window circled at the bottom once i run the code. I need it to go to debugger when i run the code in debug (shortcut = ^D)

[image]

Comment: Please check `Run - Edit Configurations - <corresponding run configuration> - Run with Python Console` option

Comment: thank you but this still doesnt work. I ticked 'run with python console' under Execution secton but still the same problem

Comment: Right, sorry, one more possible solution is: `Right Click on Console tab - Focus on Startup/Breakpoint`

Comment: I tried this and still doesnt fix it. so strange

Comment: Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54608403) it probably has the solution to the problem you described.